# How to Store foreach value into subarray and turn it in to JSON

Tags: php, json, xml, dom

How Can I store foreach value int sub array? My data[] array returning a null value.

```
foreach( $domNode -> childNodes as $node) {
  if ( $node -> hasChildNodes() ) { json2xml( $node ); }
  else {
     if ( $domNode -> hasAttributes() && strlen( $domNode -> nodeValue) ) {
        $domNode -> setAttribute( "nodeValue", $node -> textContent );
        $sub_array = array();
        $sub_array["firstname"] = $node -> nodeValue = "";
        $sub_array["lastname"] = $node -> nodeValue = "";
        $sub_array["email"] = $node -> nodeValue = "";
        $sub_array["username"] = $node -> nodeValue = "";
        $sub_array["is_block"] = $node -> nodeValue = "";

        $data[] = $sub_array;           

       }
   }
}
```

How can I store this values into subarray?
I want to convert my XML data into JSON encode using PHP and put it into jQuery Datatables. And I use foreach to call my elements and to store it into array and.

Comment: Why there is two times `=` in `$sub_array["firstname"] = $node -> nodeValue = "";` ?

Comment: Hi. I'm not familiar with sub array, im just a beginner. and I wanna know how to use sub arrays correctly

Answer (score 0):

I believe there the issue is you are `=` two times which prevents to store the value into array, try below script

```
$sub_array = array();
$data= array();
    foreach( $domNode -> childNodes as $node) {
        if ( $node -> hasChildNodes() ) { json2xml( $node ); }
        else {
            if ( $domNode -> hasAttributes() && strlen( $domNode -> nodeValue ) ) {
                $domNode -> setAttribute( "nodeValue", $node -> textContent );

                $sub_array["firstname"] = $node->nodeValue;
                $sub_array["lastname"] = $node->nodeValue;
                $sub_array["email"] = $node->nodeValue;
                $sub_array["username"] = $node->nodeValue;
                $sub_array["is_block"] = $node->nodeValue;

                $data[] = $sub_array;           
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothings Happen

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();

foreach( $domNode -> childNodes as $node) {
    if ( $node -> hasChildNodes() ) {
     json2xml( $node ); }
    elseif ( $domNode -> hasAttributes() && strlen( $domNode -> nodeValue ) ) {
            $domNode -> setAttribute( "nodeValue", $node -> textContent );
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array["firstname"] = $node->nodeValue;
            $sub_array["lastname"] = $node->nodeValue;
            $sub_array["email"] = $node->nodeValue;
            $sub_array["username"] = $node->nodeValue;
            $sub_array["is_block"] = $node->nodeValue;

            $data[] = $sub_array;           
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation to your code for the OP and future readers?

Comment: Hi, I want to convert my XML into JSON using PHP. And I use foreach to call my elements and to store it into array

Answer (score 0):

Try this one bro.

```
     $sub_array = array();
     $count = 0;
     if( $domNode->childNodes OR !empty( $domNode->childNodes)){
     foreach( $domNode->childNodes as $node) {
        if ( $node->hasChildNodes() ) { json2xml( $node ); }
        else {
        if ( $domNode->hasAttributes() && strlen( $domNode->nodeValue ) ) {
            $domNode->setAttribute( "nodeValue", $node->textContent );

            $sub_array[$count]["firstname"] = $node->nodeValue;
            $sub_array[$count]["lastname"] = $node->nodeValue;
            $sub_array[$count]["email"] = $node->nodeValue;
            $sub_array[$count]["username"] = $node->nodeValue;
            $sub_array[$count]["is_block"] = $node->nodeValue;

            $count++;       
           }
        }
      }
     }
```

Comment: maybe its good to **var_dump()** first the  $node if has. and then you can trap it to by condition

Answer (score 0):

`$sub_array["firstname"] = $node->nodeValue = "";` will first replace the whole content of the `$node` with an empty string - removing any content. After that it will assign the empty string to `$sub_array["firstname"]`.

And you assign the same `$node->nodeValue` to all the different array elements. Your code looks like it is some part generic conversion and some part specific assignment. Calling a function `json2xml()` on a DOM node makes not much sense to me.

So here is a small example for reading specific XML with DOM. Using DOM methods is possible, but it is a lot easier with Xpath:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<persons>
  <person>
    <firstname>Jane</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
  </person>
</persons>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$persons = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/persons/person') as $personNode) {
    $persons[] = [
        'firstname' => $xpath->evaluate('string(firstname)', $personNode),
        'lastname' => $xpath->evaluate('string(lastname)', $personNode)
    ];
}

var_dump($persons);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) { 
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(4) "Jane"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(3) "Doe" 
  } 
}
```

The result of `DOMXpath::evaluate()` depends on the Xpath expression. `/persons/person` will always return a node list. If here are no `person` element nodes inside a `persons` document element node it will return an empty list.

`string(firstname)` will fetch all `firstname` child element nodes of the provided context (`$personNode`) and cast the first found node into a string. If here is no match it will return an empty string.

Xpath allows for quite complex expression with combined and nested conditions. That allows you to avoid a lot of complexity (loops an conditions) in your PHP source.

Answer (score 0):

**I finally solve it. in this way.**

```
$file = @file_get_contents('user.xml', FILE_TEXT);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
$output = @$xml->xpath('/accounts/details');

$outputt = array(
  "draw" => intval($_POST["draw"]),
  "data" => $output
);

echo json_encode($outputt);
```

**Thanks for your time and answers. :)**